# Filter Search using ComboBox and TextBox VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox, textbox

i have a vb.net application with MySQL i want to search the db and filter the results using Combobox and textbox

```
        SQL = "select * FROM duty where '" & ComboBox3.Text & "' = '" & TextBox15.Text & "' "
```

Comment: There is something different here from your previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching for a string, use a **LIKE** keyword on your **SELECT** statement.

Example:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM duty WHERE '" & ComboBox3.Text & "' LIKE '" & TextBox15.Text & "%';"
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the SQL injection issues,

Add % wildcard.

```
SQL = "select * FROM duty where '" & ComboBox3.Text & "' = '%" & TextBox15.Text & "%' "
```